# Write to a file the bar plot of imhist matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to save the `imhist` plot to a file.

To save an image I use the `imwrite` function. To display its histogram, I use:

```
figure, bar(imhist(scene));
```

How do I save the resulting image to a file with `imwrite`?

Here is a sample plot generated by the `bar` function:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to save the plot as an image file (jpg, bmp, eps, etc?) or something else?

Comment: As an image file (like jpg). I tried `imwrite(bar(imhist(fig)))`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `imwrite` is used to save an image (=an array of pixel information). The figure generated by `bar` is not an 'image' in this sense yet.

To save any figure as an image, you can use [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)

It is good to know the *handle* of the figure to pass it to the `saveas` command, so you could use:

```
hfig = figure ; bar(imhist(scene));
saveas(hfig ,'MyFileName.jpg')
```

Personnaly, I find I get better results (sharper image) using `png` format instead:

```
saveas(hfig ,'MyFileName.png')
```

Look at the [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) documentation for a list of all possible formats.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/print.html) to save a plot as an image file.

To save as a jpeg, for example, use

```
print -djepg imageName
```

but you can choose from all sorts of formats, read the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand. Where do I provide the argument for the `bar(imhist(fig))` ?

Comment: You don't. The print command will save what is in the current active figure window.

Comment: It says on the documentation that `print` is for printing in a physical printer.

Comment: You can print to a file too. After you create your bar plot, call `print -djpeg imageName` and see what happens!